# A method for very efficient (fast) network polling in C

Tags: c, performance, sockets, select, polling

**Short version**: I don’t want to use third party libraries or framesworks like Netmap or DPDK, is there anything faster than `poll()` or `select()`, or can I make those calls more efficient?

**Full version**: I have a single threaded application which uses a single socket to send data as fast as possible and I'm using valgrind/cachegrind/callgrind to try and increase the efficiency (and thus, throughput of the application).

At present the receiving host sites in an infinite loop trying to check received data as fast as possible (which needs to be non-blocking, when there is no packet to process "other stuff" is done). I am using `select()` on the receiving host because `select()` uses a timeval which offers microsecond polling frequency whereas `poll()` uses a millisecond value. Callgrind is showing me that `FD_SET()` has made nearly twice as many instruction executions as the `select()` operation, and one downside to `select()` is that I must run `FD_SET()` every  iteration of the receive loop:

```
         .    .    .          .     .    .          .     .    .              // Poll for incoming frames
 4,361,236    1    1  2,180,618     0    0  2,180,618     0    0              TEST_INTERFACE->TV_SELECT_DELAY.tv_sec = 0;
 4,361,236    0    0  2,180,618     0    0  2,180,618     0    0              TEST_INTERFACE->TV_SELECT_DELAY.tv_usec = 000000;
56,696,068    2    2 15,264,326     0    0  2,180,618     0    0              FD_SET(TEST_INTERFACE->SOCKET_FD, &TEST_INTERFACE->FD_READS);
         .    .    .          .     .    .          .     .    .  
         .    .    .          .     .    .          .     .    .              TEST_INTERFACE->SELECT_RET_VAL = select(TEST_INTERFACE->SOCKET_FD_COUNT,
         .    .    .          .     .    .          .     .    .                                                      &TEST_INTERFACE->FD_READS,
         .    .    .          .     .    .          .     .    .                                                      NULL, NULL,
30,528,652    1    1 10,903,090     0    0 15,264,326     0    0                                                      &TEST_INTERFACE->TV_SELECT_DELAY);
         .    .    .          .     .    .          .     .    .  
         .    .    .          .     .    .          .     .    .  
 9,432,052    0    0  4,361,236     0    0          0     0    0              if (TEST_INTERFACE->SELECT_RET_VAL > 0 &&
 7,450,590    1    1  2,128,740     0    0          0     0    0                  FD_ISSET(TEST_INTERFACE->SOCKET_FD, &TEST_INTERFACE->FD_READS))
         .    .    .          .     .    .          .     .    .              {
         .    .    .          .     .    .          .     .    .  
         .    .    .          .     .    .          .     .    .                  RX_LEN = recvfrom(TEST_INTERFACE->SOCKET_FD,
         .    .    .          .     .    .          .     .    .                                    FRAME_HEADERS->RX_BUFFER,
         .    .    .          .     .    .          .     .    .                                    TEST_PARAMS->F_SIZE_TOTAL,
 5,321,850    1    1  2,128,740     0    0  2,838,320     0    0                                    0, NULL, NULL);
         .    .    .          .     .    .          .     .    .
```

I am getting an average of 130-140Mpbs of receive throughput using `select()`. Using `poll()` I am getting an average of 150-160Mbps.

```
         .    .    .         .     .    .         .     .    .              // Poll for incoming frames
7,347,032    2    2 1,836,758     0    0 4,591,895     0    0  TEST_INTERFACE->SELECT_RET_VAL = poll(TEST_INTERFACE->fds, 1, 0);
         .    .    .         .     .    .         .     .    .  
         .    .    .         .     .    .         .     .    .  
 3,673,516    0    0 1,836,758     0    0         0     0    0  if (TEST_INTERFACE->SELECT_RET_VAL > 0)
         .    .    .         .     .    .         .     .    .  {
         .    .    .         .     .    .         .     .    .  
 2,142,186    0    0   714,062     0    0         0     0    0      if ( TEST_INTERFACE->fds[0].revents & POLLIN )
   714,062    0    0   357,031     0    0   357,031     0    0           TEST_INTERFACE->fds[0].revents = 0;
         .    .    .         .     .    .         .     .    .  
         .    .    .         .     .    .         .     .    .                  RX_LEN = recvfrom(TEST_INTERFACE->SOCKET_FD,
         .    .    .         .     .    .         .     .    .                                    FRAME_HEADERS->RX_BUFFER,
         .    .    .         .     .    .         .     .    .                                    TEST_PARAMS->F_SIZE_TOTAL,
 5,355,465    1    1 2,142,186     0    0 2,856,248     0    0                                    0, NULL, NULL);
```

With `poll()` I am passing a timeout value of `0` so hopefully that is not blocking at all for anytime, but I'm not sure if that is correct and it is actually faster than `select()`.

In the lab I have a couple of servers back to back with 10Gbps NICs. Using `select()` with the Tx hosting sending data at line rate 10Gbps the Rx host can process about 9.5Gbps of traffic. The above results are just between to virtual machines on my laptop (the lab is out of action at present) to show that `poll()` is giving me a slight increase on the Rx host. In the above results we can see that `poll()` was faster however 10Gbps is a packet every few tens of nano-seconds so I’m not sure (when the lab is working again) if I will see any improvement.

So I guess I have two questions:

1. In my `poll()` vs `select()` tests, since I am using a single socket `poll()` is slightly faster but will this hold true on faster connections, 10/20/30/40Gbps, or at those speed would `select()` be faster?
2. Since I am only using a single socket, is there any speed increase if I switched away from `select()`/`poll()` to `epoll()`? Or is there some other “built in” method I can use, that is faster than `poll()` and `select()`, or something I can do to reduce their execution time?

Comment: Why not just do a  blocking read on the socket instead of select/poll?  You then only need one system call per read instead of two and no polling.

Comment: @MartinJames - Thanks for basically pointing out that the reasoning for that  is not clear in my question, I will update, essentially other stuff is happening inbetween packets arriving.

Comment: Actual polling, with short timeouts, is pretty hopeless for any kind of high performance.  It comes with latency, CPU, I/O and memory bandwidth waste.

Comment: @MartinJames - I appreciate the feedback, can you elaborate at all?

Comment: Are you reading from just one socket, or do you need to check for data on many?

Comment: With poll and short timeout, you're making many "round trips" between kernel and userspace even if nothing's available. You said _single_ thread [and single socket]. If you can go multithread, have one thread do blocking I/O and put "other stuff" in another thread. I've always been able to refactor in this way with good results.

Comment: @evilotto Just one socket :)

Comment: @MartinJames has the right idea - just read the socket.  If you need it to not block, then make the socket non blocking and the read will just return no data.

Comment: Polling is obsolete on modern kernels. Either read synchronously, which uses the least CPU in all cases, or use modern async IO like epoll.

Comment: @usr - Have you seen NatMap, that uses poll and is very fast: http://info.iet.unipi.it/~luigi/netmap/

Comment: Are you doing just 1 recvfrom() call whenever select()/poll() says there's data ? You'll get less overhead if you do multiple recvfrom() until you get an EWOULDBLOCK (or an upper bound on the number of recvfrom() calls you do.

Comment: @jwbensley netmap has a kernel module. They can play all kinds of tricks. Like this: http://blog.erratasec.com/2016/01/net-ring-buffers-are-essential-to-os.html

Comment: @usr Yes I know Netmap is a kernal module but people use `poll()` with Netmap, my question is requesting input on ways I can speed up `poll()` or `select()` or using something else.

Comment: @jwbensley you got that answer already: read synchronously, which uses the least CPU in all cases.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the fd(s) to select don't change you can (generally) cheat and just use a precomputed int.

```
int   fds = 1 << fd;
int   fdp;

 do {
     fdp = fds;
     n = select(fd+1, &fdp, ...
```

If FD_SET is the bottleneck, this should help some.

One of the inefficiencies with select is copying big fd_sets in/out of kernel space -- insuring that the fd is low enough to fit in int helps.

---

I'm going to assume threads are off the table.

You may also get some help from using a non-blocking socket and only calling poll/select when it says EAGAIN (and you have none of your "other work" to do).